# Linear transformation and riemannian metric tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

When is it true that for a linear transformation $A$ and a symmetric bi-linear form $g$ (i.e. (0,2) tensor) on a riemannian manifold:

$$ g( AV, W)= g(V, AW)?$$

Comment: Have you tried small examples, for example when the vector space has dimension 2?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez  I tried. it is not true in general. :)  So when is it true?

Comment: The key word is "self-adjoint".